# comprimize nested dict into more readable dict

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I currently have a nested dict like:

```
tmpDict = {0, {'TestRun1_lastRuntime': [3, 'avg'], 
               'TestRun1_maxRuntime': [5, 'max'], 
               'TestRun2_lastRuntime': [2, 'avg'], 
               'TestRun2_maxRuntime': [4, 'max'], 
              },

           1, {'TestRun1_lastRuntime': [6, 'avg'],
               'TestRun1_maxRuntime': [7, 'max'],
               'TestRun2_lastRuntime': [4, 'avg'],
               'TestRun2_maxRuntime': [5, 'max'],
              }
           }
```

I try to figure out a way to comprimize this dict into:

```
newDict = {0, {'TestRun1': [[3, 'avg'], [5, 'max']], 
               'TestRun2': [[2, 'avg'], [4, 'max']], 
              },

           1, {'TestRun1': [[6, 'avg'], [7, 'max']],
               'TestRun2': [[4, 'avg'], [5, 'max']],
               }
           }
```

First questions, is this even possible? And if yes, how can I achieve that?

Comment: This is not a dictionnary. This is a set.

Comment: And why not `{'avg': 3, 'max': 5}`?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm kinda new into this section of "dicts/sets" I just tried to figure out a way to simplify these 4 keys into 2 keys and combine their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below seems to work

```
from typing import NamedTuple


class TestStats(NamedTuple):
    avg: float
    max: float


d = {0: {'TestRun1_lastRuntime': [3, 'avg'],
         'TestRun1_maxRuntime': [5, 'max'],
         'TestRun2_lastRuntime': [2, 'avg'],
         'TestRun2_maxRuntime': [4, 'max'],
         },

     1: {'TestRun1_lastRuntime': [6, 'avg'],
         'TestRun1_maxRuntime': [7, 'max'],
         'TestRun2_lastRuntime': [4, 'avg'],
         'TestRun2_maxRuntime': [5, 'max'],
         }
     }
dd = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    seen = set()
    cnt = 0
    for kk, vv in v.items():
        if dd.get(k) is None:
            dd[k] = {}
        test_name, _ = kk.split('_')
        if vv[1] == 'avg':
            _avg = vv[0]
            cnt += 1
        elif vv[1] == 'max':
            _max = vv[0]
            cnt += 1
        if cnt == 2:
            dd[k][test_name] = TestStats(_avg, _max)
            cnt = 0
for k, v in dd.items():
    print(f'{k} -> {v}')
```

output

```
0 -> {'TestRun1': TestStats(avg=3, max=5), 'TestRun2': TestStats(avg=2, max=4)}
1 -> {'TestRun1': TestStats(avg=6, max=7), 'TestRun2': TestStats(avg=4, max=5)}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot